# Are there any disadvantages to posting a form without the <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I am trying to `$post` data to *contact_form.php* without the page refreshing or moving in anyway other than what I have a JS function tell it to do.

Someone will ask why I'm doing this.  Reason is I want my form to post without the page resting or opening the contact_form.php.

So I was thinking of trying this with no `<form>` tag.  Just build with divs

I have tried every solution below.  All of these refresh the page.

1. return=""
2. target="_blank"
3. Ajax
4. JQ solutions

**JQ still refreshes the page**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});
```

**Ajax also refreshes the page**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contact_form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'email@example.com',
            message: 'hello world!'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

I also don't want to have all email code on this page.  I would like to be able to reference the contact_form.php.

Are there any disadvantages to use an approach like this? Like security, functionality, maybe mobile version issues etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour of form submit.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    // This will prevent page refresh
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contact_form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'email@example.com',
            message: 'hello world!'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

Practical drawbacks of not using form:

1. Ugly / bad DOM
2. You won't be able to use `.submit`
3. `.serialize()` won't work because of you will need to fetch the value of all the input fields separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contact_form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'email@example.com',
            message: 'hello world!'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

You must use `preventDefault()`